# Derivative of a trace of a Hadamard product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, hadamard-product

Let $A$ be a $N\times5$ matrix, $\vec{b}$ be an $N \times 1$ vector and $\vec{x}$ be a $5\times1$ vector. I am looking for the derivative of the function,

$$f(\vec{x}) = \text{Trace}((A\vec{x}\vec{x}^TA^T - \vec{b}\vec{b}^T)\circ(A\vec{x}\vec{x}^TA^T - \vec{b}\vec{b}^T))$$

where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product.

I have checked some of the answered questions in the forum and try to derive for the solution myself but I am not sure if I derive the term correctly. What I get in the end has a sensible dimension. Can you check whether the term is correct? Or I miss anything?

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vec{x}} = 4(A\vec{x}\vec{x}^TA^T - \vec{b}\vec{b}^T)A\vec{x}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Use the chain and produc rules. The product rules states that if $B$ is a bilinear function between a product of two vector spaces into a third one that is continuous, then $B'(x_0, y_0) \cdot (h, k) = B(x, k) + B(h, y).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is **very** close -- just diagonalize the term in parentheses and pre-multiply by $A^T$.

Here are the details.

For typing convenience, define the symmetric matrix
$$\eqalign{
M &= Axx^TA^T-bb^T \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of this variable,
 then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= (I\odot I):(M\odot M) \\
  &= (I\odot M):(I\odot M) \\
df
  &= 2(I\odot M):(I\odot dM) \\
  &= 2(I\odot M):dM \\
  &= 2(I\odot M):A\,d(xx^T)\,A^T \\
  &= 2A^T(I\odot M)A:d(xx^T) \\
  &= 2A^T(I\odot M)A:2\operatorname{Sym}(dx\,x^T) \\
  &= 4\operatorname{Sym}\big(A^T(I\odot M)A\big):(dx\,x^T) \\
  &= 4\,A^T(I\odot M)Ax:dx \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
  &= 4\,A^T(I\odot M)Ax \\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
}$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix, $\odot$ is denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product, a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = \operatorname{Tr}(A^TB)$$
and Sym() is the symmetrization operator
$$\operatorname{Sym}(A) = \frac{A+A^T}{2}$$
At the risk of introducing yet another function, one might also write
$$I\odot M = \operatorname{Diag}(M)$$

Comment: Thank you very much. If I take a derivative further, it should be $4A^T(I\odot(3Axx^TA^T - bb^T))A$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is 100% correct.

Comment: I am trying to find a general form of this derivative, i.e. replacing $Ax$ with $Ax - c$. Even if $M$ is $(Ax-c)(Ax-c)^T - bb^T$, the derivative should not change much. Therefore, the first derivative is $4A^T(I\odot(Ax-c)(Ax-c)^T - bb^T)Ax$, and the second order derivative is $4A^T(I\odot3(Ax-c)(Ax-c)^T-bb^T)A$. Am 
I right? Apology for too many questions, I am never certain of my derivative with it comes to Trace and Hadamard product.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to approach the problem is to use diagonal matrices.

Define some variables. 
$$\eqalign{
y &= Ax,\quad Y=\operatorname{Diag}(y),\quad B=\operatorname{Diag}(b) \\
y &= Y{\tt1},\quad b = B{\tt1}=\operatorname{diag}(B) \\
M &= yy^T-bb^T,\quad\operatorname{Diag}(M)=Y^2-B^2 \\
}$$
Then borrow Greg's form of the objective function but with diagonal matrices instead of Hadamard products. This is especially nice because diagonal matrices are a lot like scalars, i.e. they are symmetric and commute with each other.
$$\eqalign{
f &= (I\odot M):(I\odot M) \\
  &= (Y^2-B^2):(Y^2-B^2) \\
df&= 2(Y^2-B^2):d(Y^2-B^2) \\
  &= 2(Y^2-B^2):2Y\,dY \\
  &= 4(Y^2-B^2)Y:dY \\
  &= 4(Y^2-B^2)y:dy \\
  &= 4(Y^2-B^2)y:A\,dx \\
  &= 4A^T(Y^2-B^2)y:dx \\
g=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
  &= 4A^T(Y^2-B^2)y \\
dg&= 4A^Td(Y^2-B^2)y + 4A^T(Y^2-B^2)dy \\
  &= 4A^T(2Y\,dY)y + 4A^T(Y^2-B^2)dy \\
  &= 4A^T(2Y^2)dy + 4A^T(Y^2-B^2)dy \\
  &= 4A^T(3Y^2-B^2)A\,dx \\
H=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
  &= 4A^T(3Y^2-B^2)A \\
}$$
The nice thing about writing the gradient and Hessian in terms of $y$ is that they are **unchanged** if a constant vector is added to $y$.
$$\eqalign{
y &= Ax+c \\
g &= 4A^T(Y^2-B^2)y \\
H &= 4A^T(3Y^2-B^2)A \\
}$$